# What does "false trail" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter

These lines are from *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1* (2010):

> Man: Dawlish, the Auror, has let slip that the Potter boy... ...will
> not he moved until the 30th of this month. The day before he turns 17.
>
> Snape: This is a **false trail**. The Auror Office no longer plays any
> part in the protection of Harry Potter.

What does "false trail" refer to?

Comment: A trail that is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"False trail" indicates more or less exactly what is stated. Snape believes that Dawlish is attempting to mislead them by providing information that will result in them attacking on the wrong day. He is providing *false* information to lead them down the wrong *trail*. "Down the wrong track" gets closer to the meaning that he's trying to get them to take the wrong sort of reactions, but "trail" fits better with that the Death Eaters are attempting to "track" their prey, Harry Potter.